# How to count the values in column of data frame by group in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to count the values(occurrence of numbers) in a column by group,without including NA. I know how to count unique values.

`master_data_long_sub[,freq:=uniqueN(Demand),by=.(Material)]`

```
Material  Demand
1111        2
1111        3
1111        2
1111
1111        5
2222        10
```

count of '1111' should be 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `na.rm = TRUE` to the `uniqueN` call.

`?uniqueN`

```
uniqueN(x, by=if (is.list(x)) seq_along(x) else NULL, na.rm=FALSE)
...
na.rm Logical (default is FALSE). Should missing values (including NaN) be removed?
```

EDIT after clarification comment from OP:

`master_data_long_sub[,freq:=sum(!is.na(Demand)),by=.(Material)]`

Comment: this will not work as, i dont want unique value ..even repeated values should be counted

Comment: So you're looking for the number of non-`NA` values? I edited my solution to include a solution for that.